# how to access p tag value for calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access two p tags' content and add them to a total number.

Here is html:

```
   <div id="carresult"><p id="caranswer" class="answer"></p><div class="result"> tons       CO<sub>2</sub></div> </div>

  <div id="pubresult"><p  id="pubresults" class="answer"> </p><div class="result"> tons CO<sub>2</sub></div></div>

  <button type="button" id="groundbut">Add to total</button>
    <div id="ground"><p id="groundtotal" class="answer"></p><div class="result"> tons CO<sub>2</sub></div></div>
```

I want to add "caranswer" and "pubresults" and display the total at "groundtotal"

How can i get the numeric value from p tag
javascript : this is wrong

```
        $("#groundbut").click(function(){

            $("#groundtotal").html($("#caranswer").text()+$("#pubresults").text());
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will work with more inputs as long as you add class result and will use p tag

```
$("#groundbut").click(function(){
var sum = 0;
 $("p.answer").each(function(i, item){
     var text = $(item).text();       
     if (text!= '')
     {
      sum+=parseInt(text);
     }
    });
 $('#groundtotal').text(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You´re actually quite close, you´re missing [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

The htmlvalue is a string, and two strings don't add up (like math) but concat:

```
'123' + '123' = '123123' (type is string)
parseInt('123') + parseInt('123') = 246 (type is integer)
```

In your code that would be:

```
$("#groundtotal").html( parseInt($("#caranswer").text()) + parseInt($("#pubresults").text()) );
```

To complete the answer, if you are working in strict mode, you need to define that you work in a 10-digits system (as binairy is 2):

```
parseInt('123', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$("#groundtotal").html($("#caranswer").text()+$("#pubresults").text());
```

to

```
$("#groundtotal").html( parseFloat($("#caranswer").text()) + parseFloat($("#pubresults").text()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse a string (e.g. the text of a paragraph) to a number, use `parseInt()`. This returns a number, which behaves correctly when adding to another number.

Check out the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery, try:

```
$("#groundbut").click(function(){    


    $("#groundtotal").html(parseFloat($("#caranswer").text())+parseFloat($("#pubresults").text())); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#groundbut").click(function(){
     $("#groundtotal").html(parseInt($("#caranswer").text())+parseInt($("#pubresults").text()));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SEzn3/

Comment: Just curious, why did you answer this (without guiding text aswell), while there are 4 other posts saying the exact same thing? No judging, just asking.

Comment: @Martijn i was slow to prepare the answer and by the time i posted it i got the notification that other 3 answers were posted